# Null Values and Creating Percentages for Access Query

Tags: sql, ms-access, null, expression

I am attempting to do a query that creates a percentage. Unfortunately, there are null values involved. The percentage is to create a score for employees — right now the nulls are counting as a positive in our Excel sheet. As we move to Access, they really shouldn't count as positive or negative points for the employee. I currently have it set up as a query with:

```
QAScore: (NZ([UtilizedScript])+NZ([NeedsAssessment])+NZ([PlanRecommendation])+NZ([AskedForSale])+NZ([OvercameObjections]))/200
```

Therefore, the nulls are being counted as a zero during the addition aspect. However, I would like the total possible score to reflect that null values were entered. So for example if UtilizedScript is worth 50 points and PlanRecommendation is 20 and for the employee neither of those instances were applicable, the total amount they could possibly get wouldn't be 200 — it would have been 130. Is there a way that I can add this logic to calculate for these instances without impacting the instances that are actually out of the total 200? I am very much a newbie so I'd appreciate any help I can get!

(I should have also mentioned that the values are not just not all or nothing either. For example with Utilized Script: Someone can score all for 50, Get half for 25, Get 0 for a miss, or have a null)

This is currently where I am with this (Ik its a monster in length)
QAScore: (NZ([UtilizedScript])+NZ([GatheredInfo])+NZ([Hold])+NZ([CallDisposition])+NZ([BuiltRapport])+NZ([EffectiveCommunication])+NZ([PhoneEtiquette])+NZ([Ownership])+NZ([UsedResources])+NZ([ProfessionalConduct])+NZ([AccurateInformation])+NZ([CallControl])+NZ([QualifiedCallerEligibility])+NZ([NextSteps])+NZ([NeedsAssessment])+NZ([PlanRecommendation])+NZ([AskedForSale])+NZ([OvercameObjections]))/(=IIF(Eval([UtilizedScript] In ("6","3","0")),"6","0") + IIF(Eval([GatheredInfo] In ("14","7","0")),"14","0") + IIF(Eval([Hold] In ("6","3","0")),"6","0") + IIF(Eval([CallDisposition] In ("10","5","0")),"10","0") + IIF(Eval([BuiltRapport] In ("10","5","0")),"10","0") +  IIF(Eval([EffectiveCommunication] In ("6","3","0")),"6","0") + IIF(Eval([PhoneEtiquette] In ("10","5","0")),"10","0") + IIF(Eval([Ownership] In ("8","4","0")),"8","0") + IIF(Eval([UsedResources] In ("8","4","0")),"8","0") + IIF(Eval([ProfessionalConduct] In ("20","10","0")),"20","0") + IIF(Eval([AccurateInformation] In ("18","9","0")),"18","0") + IIF(Eval([CallControl] In ("10","5","0")),"10","0") + IIF(Eval([QualifiedCallerEligibility] In ("10","5","0")),"10","0") + IIF(Eval([NextSteps] In ("8","4","0")),"8","0") + IIF(Eval([NeedsAssessment] In ("14","7","0")),"14","0") + IIF(Eval([PlanRecommendation] In ("14","7","0")),"14","0") + IIF(Eval([AskedForSale] In ("18","9","0")),"18","0") + IIF(Eval([OvercameObjections] In ("10","5","0")),"10","0"))

Comment: How many rows in the table and does the query join other tables? Yes, you could do this with a bunch of 'IIf's' in SQL, but I would create a Function in VBA that would return the proper answer.

Comment: There will be a lot of rows...because we will continually add data. Does that make a difference? I will be pulling the percentage onto a form, but not necessarily back onto the table that I queried from. You're probably going to have to talk down to me a little more than that because I only started Access recently and I'm not even sure what VBA would be that you're referring to..... is there any way that I can put it directly into the query properties field section instead?

Answer (score 0):

I think the expression you want is:

```
(NZ([UtilizedScript]) + NZ([NeedsAssessment]) +
 NZ([PlanRecommendation]) + NZ([AskedForSale]) +
 NZ([OvercameObjections])
) /
(IIF([UtilizedScript]>=0,1,0) + IIF([NeedsAssessment]>0,1,1) + 
 IIF([PlanRecommendation]>=0,1,0) + IIF([AskedForSale]>=0,1,0) +  
 IIF([OvercameObjections]>=0,1,0)
)
```

This would be easier if your data were structured with one score per row, rather than having the scores in separate columns.

Comment: Yes I have read that it would work better that way, but unfortunately I am under some constraints and not sure how I would accommodate for that based on the constraints. I think I probably should have mentioned more in my original post- the values are not either hit or a miss I have them coming in from option values, which can be 3 things Either the person gets a full score, gets half a score, gets zero, or has null for that field. I don't know much about your code response, but since it is not factoring in the 200 points and just going off three numbers, I'm guessing that wouldn't solve issue

Comment: OK, Gordon! You threw me into a head-scratching, beard pulling fit for a few minutes as I tried to figure out why in the world you were using '1' in your 'IIf' statements. After what seemed like weeks, I finally realized the OP just needs to replace the '1''s with his weights (50, 20, ?, ?)   Thanks for the additional grey hair  :)

Comment: is there a way to put an 'or.' This seems like if needs assessment is greater than 0 then 1, if not then 0. However I want it more so to say: if needs assessment is 50, 20, or 0 then 50, if null then 0. From what I'm reading online I don't think that expression would work.

Comment: i tried to do what you said and use or statements from what i found online essentially:  QAScore: (NZ([UtilizedScript])+NZ([GatheredInfo])+NZ([Hold])+NZ([CallDisposition])/=IIF(Eval([UtilizedScript] In ("6","3","0")),"6","0") + IIF(Eval([GatheredInfo] In ("14","7","0")),"14","0") + IIF(Eval([Hold] In ("6","3","0")),"6","0") + IIF(Eval([CallDisposition] In ("10","5","0")),"10","0"))   However- that doesn't work. It doesn't say anything is wrong when i paste it into the expression builder- however, when i save it and leave that field it strips the expression out of it. :( please help.